# Dúvida PostBackUrl

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estou a tentar utilizar o `PostBackUrl` em um `LinkButton` dentro da `DataList`.

Tentei o seguinte, parcialmente com sucesso.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="linkBtnMarca" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Marca") %>' **PostBackUrl='<%# string.Format("~/User/Produtos.aspx?Marca={0}", Eval("Marca")) %>'** runat="server" OnClick="linkBtnMarca_Click"><%# Eval("Marca") %></asp:LinkButton>
```

O link na barra de endereços efectivamente muda consoante a marca quando clicamos no `LinkButton`, exemplo `User/Produtos.aspx?Marca=Bosch`, mas imaginemos que não queremos clicar no `LinkButton` e queremos ir automaticamente para o link `User/Produtos.aspx?Marca=Bosch`, como poderei fazer isso? Visto que sem ir ao `LinkButton`, não funciona.

Obrigado.

EDIT:

Code Behind Marca

```
        LinkButton lnksender = (LinkButton)sender;
        Session["Marca"] = Convert.ToString(lnksender.CommandArgument);
        lblInfo.Visible = true;
        lblInfos.Visible = true;
        lblInfoGet.Visible = false;
        lblInfosGet.Visible = false;
        lblInfoPesquisa.Visible = false;
        lblInfo.Text = "A filtrar pela marca: ";
        lblInfos.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["Marca"]);
        MultiViewContent.DataBind();
        ViewGridView.DataBind();
        ViewListView.DataBind();
        DataListCategorias.DataBind();
        DataListMarcas.DataBind();
```

Comment: Como está o *Code Behind* que lê o parâmetro `Marca`?

Comment: Veja a resposta editada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<asp:LinkButton>` gera um link dentro de um `<form>` com `action = POST`. Acho que um link simples usando `GET` já resolve tudo:

```
<a href="~/User/Produtos.aspx?Marca=<%# Eval("Marca") %>"><%# Eval("Marca") %></a>
```

---

**EDIT**

Depois de inserir o link conforme acima, troque:

```
    LinkButton lnksender = (LinkButton)sender;
    Session["Marca"] = Convert.ToString(lnksender.CommandArgument);
```

Por:

```
    Session["Marca"] = Request.QueryString["Marca"];
```

Comment: Coloco em que parte?

Se colocar dentro de um botão em HTML, funciona?

Comment: Num `<button>`? Em teoria sim, porque você está usando `Session`, em que é preenchida sozinha por `queryString`.

Comment: O que eu queria é um link directo para aquela Marca, ou seja colocar no HTML User/Produtos.aspx?Marca=Bosch e ir logo para essa marca.

Comment: Tentei a sua solução, retirando o `LinkButton` e não funcionou

Comment: O que pretendo é que cada marca tenha um link próprio ou seja quando crio uma categoria, "criar" automaticamente um link dinâmico para ir automaticamente para essa marca.

Comment: @ChiragGeiantilal Experimente gerar um link fora da `DataList` apenas como teste, do jeito que coloquei na resposta. Verifique se funciona. `runat = server` pode estar influenciando no preenchimento da `Session[]`.

Comment: Seria assim? `<a href="~/User/Produtos.aspx?Marca=<%# Eval("Marca") %>"><%# Eval("Bosch") %></a>`

Comment: Na verdade pra este teste não precisa do `Eval`. Veja também que modifiquei a resposta.

Comment: Há alguma hipótese de ter `Session["Marca"] = "Bosch";
` no Load da página e igualmente `Session["Marca"] = Request.QueryString["Marca"];`

Isto para quando fizer o Load da página mostrar logo os produtos da marca Bosch mas se for pelo link `User/Produtos.aspx?Marca='MarcaPeca'` mostrar apenas os produtos da `MarcaPeca`.

Comment: Sim, você pode definir um *default* sem problemas. Por exemplo, se `Request.QueryString["Marca"]` vir vazio.

Comment: De momento tenho assim no Load:

`if (!IsPostBack)
                {
                    Session["Marca"] = "Bosch";
                }`

E se colocar igualmente no Load `Session["Marca"] = Request.QueryString["Marca"];` e aceder ao link `User/Produtos.aspx?Marca='MarcaPeca'` apenas irá retornar os produtos da marca `Bosch`.

Comment: Está resolvido.

`if (Request.QueryString["Marca"] == null)
            {
                Session["Marca"] = "Bosch";
            }

            else
            {

                Session["Marca"] = Request.QueryString["Marca"];
           
            }`